# Apex Trigger to auto populate look up field for multiple records

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex-code, apex

I am trying to update a lookup field(Benefit_ID in Customer object) with the below code, The code works fine for single record but it is failing for multiple records:

Error: "caused by: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, "

```
trigger updatelookupfield_Customer on Customer__c (before insert,before update) {
    Set<String> Bundle = new Set<String>();

    for (Customer__c Cust : Trigger.new) {
        Bundle.add(Cust.Bundle__c);
    }
List<Benfit__c> BenfitList = [SELECT id, Bundle__c FROM Benfit__c WHERE Bundle__c IN :Bundle];

    Map<String, Benfit__c> shippingNumToContactMap = new Map<String, Benfit__c>();

    for (Benfit__c c : BenfitList) {
        shippingNumToContactMap.put(c.Bundle__c, c);
    }

    for (Customer__c o : Trigger.new) {
              if (o.Bundle__c != null) {
            o.Benefit_ID__c = shippingNumToContactMap.get(o.Bundle__c).id;
        }
        else {
            o.Benefit_ID__c = null;
        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems that issue will be on line 
o.Benefit_ID__c = shippingNumToContactMap.get(o.Bundle__c).id; you are trying to get a value from a map with a key, but you are not checking if the key is present in the map.

try to add check that the key is in the map before trying to get a value for it.

```
trigger updatelookupfield_Customer on Customer__c (before insert,before update) {
Set<String> Bundle = new Set<String>();

for (Customer__c Cust : Trigger.new) {
    Bundle.add(Cust.Bundle__c);
}
List<Benfit__c> BenfitList = [SELECT id, Bundle__c FROM Benfit__c WHERE Bundle__c IN :Bundle];

Map<String, Benfit__c> shippingNumToContactMap = new Map<String, Benfit__c>();

for (Benfit__c c : BenfitList) {
    shippingNumToContactMap.put(c.Bundle__c, c);
}

for (Customer__c o : Trigger.new) {
          if (o.Bundle__c != null && shippingNumToContactMap.containsKey(o.Bundle__c)) {
        o.Benefit_ID__c = shippingNumToContactMap.get(o.Bundle__c).id;
    }
    else {
        o.Benefit_ID__c = null;
    }
}
}
```

Svata

Comment: I think it might be related to being in the before update.  Since you are updating another object base on the customer object. You'll want to make sure Customer as been completely updated.  So move this code to the after insert/update trigger on customer.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to me as though you actually need any Apex here.

So there's a Text field on Customer called Bundle__c.

You also have a custom object called Benfit__c which also has a string field called Bundle__c.

You're using the Bundle__c field on Customer to work out which Benfit__c applies to them.

Why can't you have a straight lookup from Customer to Benfit__c?